# Are there two types of runway holding position sign?

Tags: airport-markings

I came across this section on runway holding position marking while reading Jeppesen Airway Manual, which got me very confused.

[image]

[image]

My question is: Is Pattern B describing another type of runway holding position sign other than the one described in Pattern A? Or is it just describing the ILS critical area boundary marking for CAT II & III approaches? I'm asking this question because I've never heard in my whole aviation career that there are "two" runway holding position markings, nor seen one.

Comment: You are correct. It is marking the ILS critical area boundary. I think they apply to Cat I as well.(Our airpoart has them and it has a Cat I ILS)  https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/regulations/holding-short-of-ils-critical-areas/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jeppesen description is confusing (to me) but have a look at [the AIM 2-3-5](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html) and specifically Figure 2-3-16:

[image]

It looks like the pattern A image you posted shows runway holding position markings only; pattern B shows runway holding position markings *and* ILS holding position markings.

Answer (score 5):

I’ve never seen the critical area hold bars referred to as a type of runway hold bars, but they serve the same general purpose *when the critical area needs to be protected*, so I can understand the point of describing them together.

Answer (score 5):

The ["pattern B" markings](https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/Meetings/2016/ACI/D2-02HoldingPositionSigns.pdf) designate the boundary of the ILS critical area, from which [aircraft (and other things) are excluded during ILS operations](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Meetings/2012_CNS_MET_SG16/WP59_INDIA%20AI.%205%20-%20ILS%20obstruction%20criteria%20beyond%20critical%20and%20sensitive%20area.pdf). An aircraft exiting the runway knows it is safely outside the ILS critical area by passing that boundary marking.